# To make my python program interacative with webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html

I Have a python program. I want to give inputs from webpage and get output to that webpage from that python program. how can I make it.please help.thank u

Comment: Are you using any framework or it is just a core python code?

Comment: You might use django web framework, post your code here.

Comment: its core python code.  I am new to it.I don't know about  any frame work thats why i am not using  it.please suggest any resources to learn them if needed

Comment: i am giving inputs through cmd. it is classification program. i want to show output in the webpage. i am pasting my code here